# How to use multiple instances of provider in flutter with ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: value);

Tags: flutter

In my code, I'm trying to assign a unique instance of a provider to each posticon() widget using this:

ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: postProviders[index] as Response, child:postIcons(document) ,),

The postProviders variable was globally declared as a map like this:   final Map<int, Response> postProviders = {};

inside the posticon() widget, i delared  a Response provider like so postProvider = Provider.of(context); as a way of accessing the unique instance of the provider.  When i run the code, i get this error :

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Page Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that openingPage is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:

Please help.

Comment: If this is package:provider, it might be easier to consider package:riverpod, which has "family" providers that use the same code but are distinguished by a family key.  But also, if you have per-widget state that's not needed outside the widget, that's best held in a StatefulWidget.

Comment: yes, it is the provider package.